# Copying charts from Excel to PPT

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have an Excel with multiple sheets,each sheet having multiple charts.
I want to copy a chart from a specific sheet of an Excel, to a particular slideno in PPT; with specific dimensions (ie height and width) and positions using VBA.

I am able to do the same.

However,when im trying to do so; other shapes in the ppt are also getting re-positioned to the same position, along with the charts.

Here is my code

```
wkbk.Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes("chart1").Copy
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Range.Height = embededpicrange.Cells(1, 3).Value
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Range.Width = embededpicrange.Cells(1, 4).Value
```

How can we change the position of charts alone with the above code.

Need some guidance on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be help you:

```
Sub copyChartToPP()

'Declare the needed variables
Dim newPP As PowerPoint.Application
Dim currentSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim Xchart As Excel.ChartObject
'Check if PowerPoint is activate:
On Error Resume Next
Set newPP = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
'Open PowerPoint if not activate
If newPP Is Nothing Then
    Set newPP = New PowerPoint.Application
End If
'Create a new presentation in powerPoint
If newPP.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
    newPP.Presentations.Add
End If
'Display the PowerPoint presentation
newPowerPoint.Visible = True
'Locate Excel charts to paste into the new PowerPoint presentation
For Each Xchart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
'Add a new slide in PowerPoint for each Excel chart
    newPP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 
ppLayoutText
    newPP.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    Set currentSlide = 
newPP.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
'Copy each Excel chart and paste it into PowerPoint as an Metafile image
    Xchart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    currentSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select
'Copy and paste chart title as the slide title in PowerPoint
    currentSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text
'Adjust the slide position for each chart slide in PowerPoint. Note that you can 
'adjust the values to position the chart on the slide to your liking
    newPP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 25
    newPP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 150
    currentSlide.Shapes(2).Width = 250
    currentSlide.Shapes(2).Left = 500
 Next
 End Sub
```